# How to use keyboard navigation in nautilus when sidebar is hidden?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, nautilus, 19.10

When sidebar is enabled and I launch Nautilus, I can navigate on entries of sidebar with up and down keys and If I press right key focus is shifted to files pane and then I can use arrow keys to navigate over files. But I want to hide sidebar by default with the given setting. Now if I launch focus is on the top bar which has different buttons. left-right arrow keys changes focused item but I cannot use down key (or any other key) to get focus on files pane. I have to click inside files pane for it (and I want to avoid this). How can I navigate to files using only keyboard?

edit:
Ubuntu 19.10
GNOME nautilus 3.34.1
To clarify the question I want to use navigation just after launching a new nautilus window (I have already disabled sidebar).

edit2:
keyboard is standard (layout) keyboard of my Lenovo laptop.

Comment: Please edit your question to identify which version of Ubuntu are you using. Using 18.04LTS and F9 to hide the sidebar, I can still navigate the files list in Nautilus using (all) the arrow navigation keys on a standard PC keyboard.

Comment: please see edit.

Comment: Does it work after the second press of the arrow key and are you using a standard keyboard?

Comment: I am using a standard keyboard. it does not work with any number of key presses. no matter how many times I press down or up key the focused item(indicated with dash boundry) is one of the 4 buttons in top bar. and left right key navigates between them.

Comment: What is the effect if you re-enable the side bar. Do the arrow navigation keys work? When you say "standard" keyboard, please explain in your question. Is the keyboard attached by USB for example or is it part of your hardware such as in the case of a laptop. Please edit your question with extra information rather than add comments.

Comment: If I enable sidebar after launching nautilus (with F9 key) I can't even navigate to it with arrow keys as focus is stuck on top bar items. but if sidebar is already enabled (before launching) the focus is on sidebar items and I can navigate to my files with right key as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key (repeatedly) to switch focus from the title bar to the files pane.

Comment: that took lot of tab presses but still it works thanks.